# Using Net Standard library for business logic

Tags: .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

So `.NET Standard` is a formal specification of .NET APIs that are intended to be available on all .NET implementations. I have 2 applications. UI (.NET Core 3.1) and API (.NET 4.7.2).
My framework libraries are developed in .NET Standard 2.0 so I can share them between these 2 applications.

I will be developing `Domain` library that will mostly have business logic. I understand that not all .NET API are available in .NET Standard. So my business logic needs to stick to API available in .NET Standard.

I want know if the purpose of the `.NET Standard` is to develop only framework kind of libraries? Are there any drawback developing shared domain specific logic using .NET Standard?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no any drawback.
The difference only in choosing min required version of .NET standard ([link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/the-future-of-net-standard/)):

> App components. If you’re using libraries to break down your
> application into several components, my recommendation is to use
> netX.Y where X.Y is the lowest number of .NET that your application
> (or applications) are targeting. For simplicity, you probably want all
> projects that make up your application to be on the same version of
> .NET because it means you can assume the same BCL features everywhere.
>
> Reusable libraries. If you’re building reusable libraries that you
> plan on shipping on NuGet, you’ll want to consider the trade-off
> between reach and available feature set. .NET Standard 2.0 is the
> highest version of .NET Standard that is supported by .NET Framework,
> so it will give you the most reach, while also giving you a fairly
> large feature set to work with. We’d generally recommend against
> targeting .NET Standard 1.x as it’s not worth the hassle anymore. If
> you don’t need to support .NET Framework, then you can either go with
> .NET Standard 2.1 or .NET 5. Most code can probably skip .NET Standard
> 2.1 and go straight to .NET 5.